# onDestroy() is called when my application starts

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I need to understand, at which moment of time my activity is opened and when my application is closed/is in background. I thought that methods like onStop()/onDestroy() could help me. But they cannot.

This log demonstrates what happens when my application starts:

```
10-19 17:24:34 open_closed﹕ start
10-19 17:24:34 open_closed﹕ resume
10-19 17:24:48 open_closed﹕ pause
10-19 17:24:48 open_closed﹕ start
10-19 17:24:48 open_closed﹕ resume
10-19 17:24:49 open_closed﹕ stop
10-19 17:24:49 open_closed﹕ destroy
```

So the last method which is called is a `onDestroy()` method and nothing happens after, although the activity is opened, the screen is active and I can press some buttons.

How can I orrect this mistake? Or how can I understand if an activity is really opened if it was "destroyed".

I read that it can depend on configurations: here they are.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
```

What can also influence?

Comment: show your activity where you adding this log

Comment: I add this log in each onX() method

Comment: without knowing your code we can not able to help you